# Matlab: datacursormode and calculate slope

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to calculate the slope between two points.  I've tried some other methods such as imline, but none of them allows the snapping to a curve.  I found out this morning that I can possibly use the data tips in the datacursormode.

So, what I want to do is:

1. Select two points showing the black dot for both points
2. Upon the second left-clicking, a line is drawn connecting the two points and a text box shows the calculated slope
3. If I move either black dot, the text box is updated with a new slope
4. I can have as many pairs as I want, many lines between a part of black dots
5. If either dot is deleted, the associated text box disappears along with it

I've tried things like

```
  waitforbuttonpress;
  point1 = getCursorInfo(data_cursor_mode_obj);
  waitforbuttonpress;
  point2 = getCursorInfo(data_cursor_mode_obj);
  slope = abs((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
  text((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2,[' \leftarrow' num2str(slope) ])
```

This of course doesn't update the text.  In fact, for some reason, Matlab complains and I don't know how to fix it.

Another thing I tried was using UpdateFcn, but a problem with it is that I can only pass one point data by doing event_obj.Position.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: You dont have the points before plotting? do you need to obtain them from the plots?

Comment: Seems like a big project! Something to start from http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/282843.

Comment: Correct.  The data need to be extracted from the plot.  So, it's a big project.....dang it!